# Algolia tag not searchable when ending with special characters

Tags: algolia

I'm coming across a strange situation where I cannot search on string tags that end with a special character. So far I've tried `)` and `]`.

For example, given a Fruit index with a record with a tag `apple (red)`, if you query (using the JS library) with `tagFilters: "apple (red)"`, no results will be returned even if there are records with this tag.

However, if you change the tag to `apple (red` (not ending with a special character), results will be returned.

Is this a known issue? Is there a way to get around this?

**EDIT**

I saw this [FAQ](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/how-can-i-search-for-punctuation-special-characters) on special characters. However, it seems as though even if I set `()` as separator characters to index that only effects the direct attriubtes that are searchable, not the tag. is this correct? can I change the separator characters to index on tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the array syntax for your tags:

```coffee
tagFilters: ["apple (red)"]
```

The reason it is currently failing is because of the syntax of `tagFilters`. When you pass a string, it tries to parse it using a special syntax, documented [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#tagfilters-deprecated), where commas mean "AND" and parentheses delimit an "OR" group.

By the way, `tagFilters` is now deprecated for a much clearer syntax available with the [`filters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#filters) parameter. For your specific example, you'd use it this way:

```coffee
filters: '_tags:"apple (red)"'
```